# Vue 3 pattern for multiple layouts in component

Tags: vuejs3

I am working on a Vue3 component. According to the design, there are two slightly different variations of the layout, a simplified example:

1. Two inner components in the top row, slot below them

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
   <div class="flex">
      <InnerComponent1/>
      <InnerComponent2/>
   </div>
   <slot/>
</div>
```

2. Two inner components in the left column, slot on the right

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
   <div class="flex">
      <InnerComponent1/>
      <slot/>
   </div>
   <InnerComponent2/>
</div>
```

What is the right way to implement this in Vue 3? One obvious way is to pass a `layout` property, then just duplicate the whole div with `v-if="layout === 'type1'"` etc., but this doesn't look good, there will be a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You could create each layout as its own component replacing all content with slots. Then use a [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) to choose which layout to use at runtime. Insert the desired content into each slot, and then let the dynamic component handle the layout of those slots.

**LayoutA.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex">
      <slot name="inner1" />
      <slot name="inner2" />
    </div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

**LayoutB.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex">
      <slot name="inner1" />
      <slot />
    </div>
    <slot name="inner2" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Component.vue**

```html
<template>
  <component :is="layout">
    <template #inner1>
      <InnerComponent1 />
    </template>
    <template #inner2>
      <InnerComponent2 />
    </template>
    <template #default>
      <slot />
    </template>
  </component>
</template>

<script setup>
  import LayoutA from './LayoutA.vue';
  import LayoutB from './LayoutB.vue';

  const layout = ... // insert logic here that decides LayoutA or LayoutB
</script>
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNrFVV9v2jAQ/yqn7AGQSlKo9pLRbmXqQ6dpq7Y95iUkR3DrOJHtUBDKd9/ZiZPQMtRJkyYhYd/97nfn+5eDd1uW/rZCL/QWKpGs1DeRCAL4XmpWCAW3D/cgEFNMQRcgMWNKo4SkyMtCoNAKeJHEnO/9xkzwPeETVCqWe2BrqBQTGaR7Eecs6e3gmenN4EpqBKUlgVVDtdG6VGEQUHCPyi9kFmQVSzEgajJgMVdBZz5dxYolyt/onL9rfU37GCPB6Cg1fI33RaVvYS2LHEZ+0N5NAkYfXqCWL1BLh8KdRaW4jiuu4RAJGOQjhINzc9Ex1ZGg3yLoMkyX5gwKdVWSpPV9oByvoW59tx4jkVAtNHBLB9cGMx61XkaTSKwrkZh6UY2yjON40kTV4P1tzCskq+PrNXQM8NGdlyMIe/mJqDXmJY810g1gsaq0Jq9K7zleR14ey4yJ6aogaR7C+8tyF3nwKeEseSJ1E1zk3TQH95zx4eBCU4TE8XQ2gbqeLIKG3rqy7vp2CZkiwsaKCI2W9C44eMeEQDlr5aRJ2RYSHitjZXVkZP9hRrUTmjgXAYEcU3D0ztfU87dQz/+Wum2p09ytkthd5yle6De4WPRzQvcjpWlDUzs6+kf9/MxSvQlhfkklpAYE2CDLNnooWRUyRRnCrNyBKjhLYUV9RSrqGb9JgKXqyK46055uKHtNKDFt+dYcd44uZYri34dghAM9DTx3GHtPmUQ7FiFliVe5aMDU0PbN3oWnFaVvzTL/URWCVqC1jjyTL8ZRtksw8mioG97Io11XPH+xMi0rvHDyZIPJ0wn5o6IZCOnwIFGh3FL/dzpN84JUUaO++/kNd3TulHmRVmZazih/IOWpMjE2sGUlUgp7gLPR3tvVQpv1l7rbUbMo9ygTqEHWFh95tG4+n3l6H+6Vf2XtKJ+UxcEWNZ+Rvr+kbb9hE9s6umKZwbWQE6CBjrS2080nws3YjPZKcBYxP0K04+FuFu20vW44G3S1Irf86Pxq8Vtz43S4M0lYN2QD0y5L9ivyf7N0Pit/yuG/zNLyRJa8+jdDZuX2)